# Hide Alchemy from non-Admin usser

Tags: web8.5

We installed Alchemy in our WEB 8 environment, which works great. However, I want to hide Alchemy from the list of options for non-admin users. Can someone show me how to config that?
Thanks!

[image: alchemy]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Velmurugan says, there isn't a configuration setting for this.

You can control who can install, uninstall and configure Alchemy plugins through the Alchemy Control Room, but you cannot completely hide the Alchemy link from the slide-out navigation in configuration.

One option would be to create a GUI Extension to hide this based on the user, but this would require custom development and deployment.

Comment: Thanks @Velmurugan and Jonathan. We will try the Control Room approach.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the answer. I'm on the Alchemy dev team and we're currently working on adding this functionality so stay tuned for updates on the A4T release blog https://www.alchemywebstore.com/blog . I'll update this post when the feature is released.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that it's not.

That needs to be handled in the right side window page based on Custom page Authentication.

Or you can decide to hide completely that link by changing the following manifest settings config find and remove **applicationReference** tag of Alchemy from below mentioned XML.

> [Install Location]\SDL Web\web\SDL\settings.xml

For this change required cache refresh, go to this path and update System.config to increase the modification number and recycle the SDL Tridion App pool in IIS

> [Install localtion]\SDL
>   Web\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config
>
> <server version="8.5.0.22656" modification="18">