# Hide Setting from non-admin users

Tags: web8.5

We just setup new WEB 8.5 environment and I noticed that non-admin users can see the Setting menu below.

How can I hide the "Setting" from non-Admin users (high lighted in RED)?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Duplicated, https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17763/hide-alchemy-from-non-admin-usser,  there isn't a specific configuration setting for this to hide only for non-Admin users, As we mentioned one option to create a GUI Extension to hide this based on the user/group, but this would require custom development and deployment.

Comment: Thanks. I would think this is a common requirement and should be part of Tridion itself. I didn't realize this is also custom development.

Comment: I am not sure I explained in the question clearly. I am asking how to hide "Setting", not the alchemy in this question.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I believe the proper solution is to take away  the rights of those users so that they will not see the "Setting" tab.

The rights to take away is "Publication Management".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Charles for proof most TRex users aren't typical users. :-) I believe removing Publication Management makes sense since there's a "Sites" section in the Settings view. This was similar to how the Group Management right gave access to the Administrative section (otherwise users with Group Management couldn't navigate to the section).